# How to iterate through row values in a dataframe colunm In R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a table

[image]

I would like to create a loop that prints the rows in each string in the **region_mu** field. For example all "VRO1" would return all the rows that have VR01 has the region_mu value, as well as VR02 and VR03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `split` to split the data into `list` of data.frames based on the unique value of 'region_mu'

```
lst1 <- split(df1, df1$region_mu)
```

The individual elements can be extracted with `$` or `[[`

```
lst1$VR01
```

---

If it should be a `for` loop

```
un_region <- unique(df1$region_mu)
out <- vector('list', length(un_region))
names(out) <- un_region
for(un1 in un_region) {
      tmp <- subset(df1, region_mu == un1)
      print(tmp)
      out[[un1]] <- tmp
}
```

Comment: I would like a for loop so I can iterate the process

Comment: thanks but it's only returning the first one "VR01" , do you know why

Comment: @Oladapo You earlier said that you want to `print`.  So, I changed the more efficient code to `for` loop.  `print` doesn't `return` anything.  It just prints.  If it is not printing the other values, check the `str(df1)`

Comment: I would like it to return the rows for VRO1 , VR02... so I can then use it in other parts of my code

Comment: @Oladapo you may need to store the output in a `list`.  which is more easier in the first line with `split`.  Sorry, I am not sure what you really wanted to do

Comment: thank you, one final question, is there a way to get the tmp result outside the for loop, so I can use the values for other part of my code

Comment: @Oladapo The `tmp` is stored in a `list` now.  So you can get a specific dataset as `out[[1]]` or `out[[2]]` or by its name i..e `out$VR01` etc.